# Using scripts in PackageMaker (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, scripting, packagemaker

I'm trying to build an install package on Mac for my application(s) (there are two .app-s). One of them is a GUI and the other is an agent (service). The install package must run a script (that's the only way I know it can be done) at the end of the installation, so that the agent would be installed as an agent. There is also a .plist file that is installed in /Library/LaunchAgents, but that's what PackageMaker does automatically (ie without the need of a script).

The problem is that... I can't make the script run. I get "Installation failed" at the end.
I don't know what the problem is. Can somebody please help?

A few more details:

- I'm trying to do this at the postflight step (after the installation is done). just a guess... do I need to call my file with the same name (eg. postflight)?
- I suppose this is the correct directory and path I have set. After dozens of attempts, in the last one I set as "relative path" the path where the PackageMaker document is (in the same folder I have the script). Is there something important I should know about paths that might cause the problem? (the fact is, however, that the build is successful)
- do I have to write something specific to allow the script to be executed? I've got the following script:
  MyInstall.sh

with the following contents (without quotes):

"#!/bin/sh

sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.MyCompany.MyService.plist"

(note that com.Mycompany.MyService.plist is already there - it puts it there on install).

P.S. In some of my attempts to make it work, PackageMaker crushed.

Can anybody PLEASE help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the installation log.

When the **Installer** application is running, go to the **Window** menu and select **Installation Log**. This will open a separate log window. In this window, select **Display All** from the combo box. You will be able to see why your script is failing.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it has info (like logs) written somewhere, nor where that could have been. I'm not sure what I have done to make it work (perhaps the fact that I set the script as executable, using chmod), or I don't know what else I did that mattered, but after doing it, I tried again and it worked. Thanks for telling me about the logs and where to find it (now I'll be able to see the reasons when something happens)

Answer (score 0):

I had such experience myself. And here's what i've found out.
In order for installation to succeed your sript must explicitly return 0(i.e. 'success').
If result of commands in your script is not 0 and you aren't calling

```
exit 0
```

as last script sentense, your install will tell you it failed.

If you don't use script's return value and you are sure scrpit works correct - just add '**exit 0**' at the last line of script.